# Add see more/see less button customized

Tags: javascript, button

I want to add a see more/see less button with customization: the custom is a plus (+) icon as the image below.
[image: See more button]
I was able to doing this with the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

if (dots.style.display === "none") {
 dots.style.display = "inline";
 btnText.innerHTML = "See more here"; 
 moreText.style.display = "none";
} else {
 dots.style.display = "none";
 btnText.innerHTML = "See less"; 
 moreText.style.display = "inline";
}
}
```

```css
/*read more button*/
#more {
display: none;
}

.fa-plus-circle {
font-size: 40px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
vertical-align: super;
color: #a41a3c;
}

.fa-plus-circle:before {
content: "\f055";
}

#myBtn {
background-color: #fff;
border: none;
width: 13%;
}

#myBtn h4 {
font-size: 13px;
margin: 17px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<span id="dots"></span>
<div id="more" style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="col-xs-12">
<!-- here are the hidden <div> -->
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
  <h4>See more here</h4>
 </button>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I click the button, the style of the button disappear and the icon as well as below image:
[image: See less button]
I would like to keep the style of the button and also change the icon with a minus (-) icon.

Can anybody help me on this situation please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see is basically because of the more div in your code as everything else is placed in it as a child so when more display gets none you don't see the style getting applied.I think you should avoid changing styles of the more div and then see whats happening

Answer (score 1):

I think the `btnText.innerHTML` where reversed in the function. Also, you forgot to look for the `h4`, you were replacing everything of `#myBtn`.

Note: It's better to add css classes than to change style.

Try

```js
function myFunction() {

 var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
 var btnText = document.querySelector("#myBtn h4"); 

 if (dots.classList.contains("hidden")) {

   dots.classList.remove("hidden");
   btnText.innerHTML = "See less"; 
 } else {
   dots.classList.add("hidden");
   btnText.innerHTML = "See more here"; 
 }
}
```

```css
/*read more button*/

.hidden {
   display: none;
}

.centering {
   text-align: center;
}

.bottom_spacer {
   margin-bottom:20px;
}

.fa-plus-circle {
   font-size: 40px;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
   vertical-align: super;
   color: #a41a3c;
}

.fa-plus-circle:before {
   content: "\f055";
}

#myBtn {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: none;
   width: 13%;
}

#myBtn h4 {
   font-size: 13px;
   margin: 17px 0 0 0;
   white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<span id="dots" class="hidden">(+) something  (+) somethingelse</span>
<div id="more" class="col-xs-12 bottom_spacer">
 <div class="row centering">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">
   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
   <h4>See more here</h4>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. The function works properly. However I have an other concern: the icon is still the + icon when I would like the - icon when this is 'see less' button. How can I change it? Thank you again for your time and support.

Comment: @AlexandreDeplancke Use one css class to specify a background (+) image or another for a (-) image.

Comment: I understand the way to create 2 different CSS class. However I don't know how to write the code correctly as I am not a good developer. Should I use only CSS or the function code change also? Any help please?

Comment: Any help please on how to change a background (+) image for a (-) image when the "see more" button is clicked and become "see less"? I am sorry as I am not a good developer and would like to learn. Thank you.